# How nonce and timestamp prevent replay attacks

Tags: cryptography, cloud

In cloud computing, the data owner outsources the data to the cloud service provider and then challenges the server to check if data is intact or not.
So consider that the data owner challenges the server, the server can cache the response to use it later in the same challenge (replay attack) so how can a nonce or timestamp prevents replay attack?
As the server can get the cached reponse and sends it with the new timestamp without possessing the data

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is not really a replay attack. A replay attack is when you can *reuse* a response to an earlier challenge. What you are doing is simply to send the response at a later time; to withhold the response in other words.

The owner should make sure that a response if forthcoming in a specific time period. This is also a reason why a time-stamp is regularly used. If no response is forthcoming, the owner should try again, using a brand new challenge instead of the original one.

Of course, a response should cover the timestamp as well. A challenge-response over an old challenge should not be considered valid.